# jQuery AJAX request for code igniter rest url gives bad request always

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, codeigniter

I have a code igniter rest api. When I access the url from rest client(post man) its working fine. But when i access it from a html page(browser) it always gives 400-Bad request as a response.My ajax function code is below.

```
    $("#login").click(function() {
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var pass = $("#password").val();

    var obj = 
            {
             email: email, 
             password: pass}

    var jsonData= JSON.stringify( obj);


        $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://www.example.com/dictionaryapi/UserController/login',
        data: jsonData,
        success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(responseData);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    })
   })
```

Comment: url should be like this   `url: "<?=base_url('UserController/login');?>"`

Comment: Try adding content type and data type in AJAX. contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            dataType: "json"

Answer (score 0):

add **dataType** and **contentType** to yuor ajax request

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://www.example.com/dictionaryapi/UserController/login',
        data: jsonData,
        dataType:'json',
        contentType:'application/json',
        success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(responseData);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    })
```

Comment: please accept and upvote answer if it is useful to you.